# Parsing of Fiddlers response

Tags: fiddler

I would like to save some part of responses which was captured by Fiddler to TXT file.

But seems oSession.responseBodyBytes is not accessible at OnPeekAtResponseHeaders() and OnPeekAtResponseHeaders()

Where is right place where can I put "processing code"?

Answer (score 1):

The `OnPeekAtResponseHeaders` event runs when the response headers have been received, *before* the response body has been received. The `responseBodyBytes` array is available for processing in the `OnBeforeResponse` event or the `OnAfterSessionComplete` event.

Keep in mind that most HTTP response bodies aren't text (e.g. they're binary images, etc). You may wish to call `utilDecodeResponse` to remove chunked encoding and compression before saving to a file.